How to control points position separate from the world orientation in geometry nodes?
I wanna be able to control the points position separate from the worlds orientation, and have it in a way that I can secondarily randomize their position but along each axis using a noise texture.


Please elaborate. It’s unclear (to me) what your exact desire is. Is definitely unclear what you’ve tried, what troubles you’re having, and what your question is.

hi, thanks for the response, im new to GN, i need to know how i can manipulate the positions of points on a curve in Blender using Geometry Nodes. Specifically, i want to move these points along their own local axes (tangent, normal, and binormal) rather than the global world axes. i have many uses for this but i tried simplifying the idea as much as i could, i later wanna be able to add a noise texture to drive some points up and down but i need it to be along a those 3 axis i mentioned, not world space.

(Using Blender 4.2.1)
The Sample Curve node is providing the local Tangent and Normal to a curve for a given Position. This Position is also an output ; as input, the relative (i.e. Factor) or the absolute (i.e. Length) curvilinear abscissa is required. In the following demonstration, combining Set Position nodes, White points are evenly put along the curve ; "Red" points are shifted along the tangent ; "Blue" points are shifted along the normal.

Resources:

Blender file: (Blender 4.2.1+)
Shader: see How do I assign random colors to points?

